# How can I complete the optional objective on the Space Jam sidequest?

Tags: borderlands-the-pre-sequel

When you are asked to slam down onto the hoop, there is an optional objective to do it while on fire.
There are multiple incendiary barrels nearby to use, but when you use the jump pad, you go outside of the zone with oxygen, and the fire goes out.

Is it possible to complete this optional objective? And if so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible to complete this optional objective. I just did it.

As you know, there are incendiary barrels nearby. There is even one right next to the jump pad you are supposed to use, facing the basketball net (the same one the other guy used).

So, I shot the barrel while standing next to it, which lit me on fire. I then immediately moved to the jump pad, which propelled me to the basketball net. I don't recall if you need to also use an oxygen boost to get as far as possible; use it if necessary.

But, I think the key is to always be looking down, because once you are almost above the basketball net, then immediately crouch to slam down onto the net. This got me both the optional and primary objectives.

Although to clarify, the secondary objective of lighting yourself on fire marked itself as complete for me immediately once I launched myself into the air, so even if the fire goes out, I would imagine you already get the objective anyway since it's already been marked.

Comment: Oh this makes sense. When I lit myself on fire, I missed the hoop. Then I realized that you go outside of the oxygen zone and that the fire will go out as you fly, so I thought it couldn't be done. So even though it goes out, it still counts. Thanks!